# Equvialent of countif in excel within a tm1 rule?

Tags: rules, cognos-tm1

I want to count cells that include 'EVET' string keyword via below's picture

[image]

and paste number of each month into each month, respectively to below's picture

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add an additional (numeric) measure into the v_measure dimension in the "v_planning 02" cube. For the example, I will call it "EVET Count"

You then add a rule in the "v_planning 02" cube as below:

```
['v_measure':'evet count']=N: If ( DB ( 'v_planning 02', !v_months, !v_row, 'Achieved' ) @= 'EVET', 1, 0 );
```

You will want to have skipcheck enabled in this cube and then feed to the "EVET Count" measure (from somewhere sensible) so that it consolidates up correctly.

Because v_row does not exist in your "v_key performance indicator" cube; you need to sum up the count in the "v_planning 02" cube instead. To do this you will need to have a Consolidated element in the v_row dimension, I will assume you have one called "Total".
In the "v_key performance indicator" cube your rule would then be:

```
['v_revenue':'Total Achieved']=N: DB ( 'v_planning 02', !v_months, 'Total', 'EVET Count');
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and I want to know that why I enabled skipcheck, Can you please explain it? I am appriciate for your help